# Prepared SQL LIKE statement not returning all results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a function to search my ingredient DB (error reporting removed for clarity):

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "*****";
    $dbname = "addb_db";

    $query = "%" . $_POST["query"] ."%";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM addb_ingredients WHERE name LIKE ? or id like ?";
    $stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql)
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $query,$query)
    $stmt->execute()
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$name)
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $ing_array[] = array($id,$name);
    }
    $response_array["status"] = "success";
    $response_array["data"] = $ing_array;

    echo json_encode($response_array);


    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
```

This only returns partial results for particular queries, e.g. for "bi", these are the results returned:

- Bison Grass Flavored Vodka
- Bitter
- Bitter Lemon
- Bitters
- Celery Bitters
- Chilled hibiscus tea
- Chocolate Bitters
- Orange Bitters
- Peach Bitters
- Peychaud's bitters
- Wasabi Paste

[Running this query on phpMyAdmin returns the same, as it should.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzIyb.png)

However, when entering "bit", the results from the php above are:

- Bitter Lemon
- Bitters
- Celery Bitters
- Chocolate Bitters
- Orange Bitters
- Peach Bitters
- Peychaud's bitters

Whereas the results should be:

[image]

The 'bitter' result is excluded and I can't work out why.

Comment: simple/silly test: does 'bitter' show up if you do `not like '%bit%'`? perhaps one of those character isn't really a b/i/t, or has otherwise unprintable characters in there. a simple `select length(name) where id='bitter'` would tell you that.

Comment: Good idea, sadly the results from `not like '%bit%'` didn't include bitter.

Comment: very odd. can't see how a 'like' and 'not like' would both exclude the value...

Comment: I have just found another occurrence. 'bo' returns 'Bourbon' and 'Bourbon, Peach Flavored' (among other items that don't start with 'bou') whereas 'bou' returns just 'Bourbon, Peach Flavored'. It seems to omit the simpler entry when an extended one exists..

Comment: The query should run just fine, try print_r $ing_array[], see if you get all the result.

Comment: @LiKiaChiu 'bitter' and 'bourbon' are still not included.

Comment: how about something like `'%ou%'`? start fiddling with the strings.

Comment: I made a table for 'bitter' showing every combination: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aekLuaKELRF3P0jGyenA_GR1rqS1sLyOE6Xy7RHDqQw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried with your code, no problem, so I am guessing is the $query = "%". $_POST["query"] ."%".  , try echo the $query, see if you do get %bit%., or try with $query ="%bit%" first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not particularly strong with PHP, but I've noticed that `'Bitter'` would have been the first result if using `'%bit%'` as a parameter. Likewise, `'Absolut Hibiskus'` should be the first result when using `'%bi%'` as a parameter.

My guess is that the first result is consumed within this block of code without actually being assigned anywhere within `$ing_array`:

```
$stmt->bind_result($id,$name)
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $ing_array[] = array($id,$name);
}
```

Comment: Good spot. The validation code that I didn't include contained another `$stmt->fetch()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quite indicative, there are no screenshots for the actual output provided. Means the OP is judging their prepared statement output by distant indirect consequences. Like some processing on the client side.

There are no errors neither in prepared statements nor in LIKE statement responsible for such a behavior. 100% of reported errors of the same kind were caused by the userland code.